# Query takes a long time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query (in oracle) which takes a very long time (between 15-30secs) (*query1*):

```
SELECT numcen
  FROM centros
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (centros.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (?)
    OR TO_NUMBER (centros.numcen) IN (
          SELECT TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
            FROM datos_centro dc, centros c
           WHERE TO_NUMBER (c.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
             AND TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior) = TO_NUMBER (?));
```

I don't know why, because it's a very simple query. I thought it was because of subquery inside `IN`, but if I run such subquery (*query2*):

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
  FROM datos_centro dc, centros c
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (c.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
   AND TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior) = TO_NUMBER (?)
```

It only takes 100-200ms. 
Even more, if I run *query2* and I put its result inside `IN` in *query1* replacing subquery, result is immediate.

I can't run an Explain Plan because I have no rights. 
It's even worse under if I run under mysql (replacing `TO_NUMBER` by `CAST`). It takes more than 2mins, which is unacceptable.

So, is there a way to improve first query (*query1*)? Should I split into two? Will it be the same query if I replace `OR` by `UNION` (which is much faster)?

Any advice will be very welcome. Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: What is important to you? The result or the method? Decide on that and let me know.

Comment: The result, of course. But it's unacceptable such query (_query1_) takes more than 15secs. It should take not even 1sec. It's very simple.

Comment: What's going on with all this to_number() business? If they're stored in a numeric data type then take out the function -- if they're not then you've got a database design problem.

Comment: Tell you what's unacceptable -- not having access to explain plan.

Comment: I know, it's not my design and I can't alter such tables. Those are auxiliary tables provided by an external provider used by many j2ee applications. Sadly, we have to deal with it. In this case `numcen` field was a `VARCHAR2(4)` and now it's a `VARCHAR(5)` which only stores numbers. Unbelievable, right? That's why I need `TO_NUMBER()`. In that table I can find '1111' or '01111', which represents same 'center'.

Comment: Why do you not have explain plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing centros in your subquery is redundant.

try:

```
SELECT numcen
  FROM centros
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (centros.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (?)
    OR TO_NUMBER (centros.numcen) IN (
          SELECT TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
            FROM datos_centro dc
             AND TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior) = TO_NUMBER (?));
```

... or ...

```
SELECT numcen
  FROM centros
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (centros.numcen) IN (
          SELECT TO_NUMBER (?)
            FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
            FROM datos_centro dc
             AND TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior) = TO_NUMBER (?));
```

If you don't need those TO_NUMBER() functions then get rid of them, or add function-based indexes on TO_NUMBER(centros.numcen) and TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior).

Comment: First attempt didn't help. It takes as much time as mine. However, second one lasts a few milliseconds, as I expected. I also tried `SELECT TO_NUMBER (numcen)
  FROM centros
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (centros.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (?)
UNION
SELECT TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
  FROM datos_centro dc, centros c
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (c.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
   AND TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior) = TO_NUMBER (?)` and also works really fast and it should return same data. Sorry for formatting. I don't know how to format properly in comments. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, I need `TO_NUMBER` because `numcen` is a `VARCHAR2(5)` field and '0001' must be the same than '1' or '00001'.

Comment: See note on adding function-based indexes also then.

Comment: I didn't know anything about function-based indexes. I'll take a look on that. Thanks.

Comment: I think they're about to save your life.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a explain plan on your two queries. 
explain plan for [ your sql ]; 
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

The optimizer will tell the different between different plans.

Looks to me, the first query will have to use a nested loop and go through each rows in centros and evaluate each record in subquery to filter it out.

The second query will do a hash join between these two tables and do two read then join. This is much less work.

Answer (score 0):

U just try to use  global temp table concept ,insert result set of sub qry in temp table and then use select * from temp table or directly join it with your main qry.

I am sure ,this will improve your performance by manyfold , even i had this issue .

Just give try and let me know if u have any prob.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
  column1  NUMBER) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

insert into my_temp_table 

  SELECT TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
  FROM datos_centro dc, centros c
 WHERE TO_NUMBER (c.numcen) = TO_NUMBER (dc.centro)
   AND TO_NUMBER (dc.centro_superior) = TO_NUMBER (?)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no permissions to create new tables. It's a very restrictive environment, where DDL statements are NOT allowed.

Comment: then try puting this sub qry in function and call this function in your main qry... output of the function shd be sys_ref cusrsor

Comment: I expected an easier solution. I guess I will split query into two, first _query2_ and then I'll put its result in _query1_. Nevertheless, I still don't understand why _query1_ takes so much time. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain that this will not solve the problem. In general splitting a single query into multiple queries harms performance, and the only way I see this improving the situation is if dynamic sampling against the result set in the GTT improves the optimiser's plan for the main query. I doubt it.

Comment: I agree, and that's the key of my concern. As I said, if I run subquery, and put their results into `IN` (removing subquery, of course), it takes just a few milliseconds. I don't understand.